# Laravel 5.8 mail Class not found, when send a mail

Tags: php, laravel

This is my controller Settings.php. I am using laravel 5.8

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Mail;
use App\Mail\RichiestaAssistenzaCreazione;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\RichiesteAssistenza;
//use Carbon;

class Settings extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'titolo' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'figura_professionale' => 'required|string|max:100',
            'esperienza' => 'nullable',
            'persona_da_accudire' => 'required',
            'regione' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'provincia' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'citta' => 'required|string|max:100',
            'zona' => 'nullable|string|max:100',
            'indirizzo' => 'nullable|string|max:255',
            'assistenza_ospedaliera' => 'nullable',
            'durata'  => 'required|string|max:50',
            'data_inizio' => 'required|date_format:d/m/Y',
            'data_fine' => 'required_if:durata,a tempo determinato',
            'descrizione' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'servizi_aggiuntivi' => 'nullable',
            'budget' => 'required|string|max:10',
            'tipo_budget' => 'required|string|max:50',
            'sesso' => 'required|string|max:25',
            'fumatore' => 'nullable',
            'lingua_madre' => 'nullable|string|max:255',
            'altre_lingue' => 'nullable',
            'tipo_disponibilita' => 'nullable',
            'max_giornaliere' => 'nullable|date_format:d/m/Y',
            'giorni_disponibilita' => 'nullable',
        ]);
        
        RichiesteAssistenza::create([
            'id_cliente' => $request->input('id_cliente'),
            'titolo' => $request->input('titolo'),
            'figura_professionale' => $request->input('figura_professionale'),
            'esperienza' => isset($request['esperienza']) ? implode(', ', $request['esperienza']) : '',
            'persona_da_accudire' => isset($request['persona_da_accudire']) ? implode(', ', $request['persona_da_accudire']) : '',
            'regione' => $request->input('regione'),
            'provincia' => $request->input('provincia'),
            'citta' => $request->input('citta'),
            'zona' => $request->input('zona'),
            'indirizzo' => $request->input('indirizzo'),
            'assistenza_ospedaliera' => $request->has('assistenza_ospedaliera') ? $request->input('assistenza_ospedaliera') : NULL,
            //isset($request['assistenza_ospedaliera']) ? implode(', ', $request['assistenza_ospedaliera']) : '',
            'durata'  => $request->input('durata'),
            'data_inizio' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime($request->input('data_inizio'))),
            'data_fine' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime($request->input('data_fine'))),
            'descrizione' => $request->input('descrizione'),
            'servizi_aggiuntivi' => isset($request['servizi_aggiuntivi']) ? implode(', ', $request['servizi_aggiuntivi']) : '',
            'budget' => $request->input('budget'),
            'tipo_budget' => $request->input('tipo_budget'),
            'lingua_madre' => $request->input('lingua_madre'),
            'altre_lingue' => isset($request['altre_lingue']) ? implode(', ', $request['altre_lingue']) : '',
            'sesso' => $request->input('sesso'),
            'fumatore' => $request->input('fumatore'),
            'tipo_disponibilita' => isset($request['tipo_disponibilita']) ? implode(', ', $request['tipo_disponibilita']) : '',
            'max_giornaliere' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime($request->input('max_giornaliere'))),
            'giorni_disponibilita' => isset($request['giorni_disponibilita']) ? implode(', ', $request['giorni_disponibilita']) : '',
            
        ]);

        Mail::to('mymail@icloud.com')->send(new RichiestaAssistenzaCreazione());
       
        
        return redirect('/profilo-cliente')->with("status", "La tua richiesta è stata registrata con successo! Ti è stata appena inviata una E-mail con i tuoi dati di accesso, e con i dati della tua richiesta. N.B: Se hai richiesto delle opzioni a pagamento, assicurati di completare il pagamento tramite Paypal, altrimenti tali opzioni non potranno essere applicate alla tua richiesta! Richiesta creata con successo, in attesa di approvazione da parte dell’admin");;

    }

    public function create()
    {
        return view('richieste_assistenza.settings');
    }

  
}
```

This is RichiestaAssistenzaCreazione.php stored in app/Mail

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class RichiestaAssistenzaCreazione extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->from('no-reply@badando.it')->view('emails.richiesta_assistenza_create');
    }
}
```

I'am try to send an email with the class RichiestaAssistenzaCreazione().

When i send return error Class 'App\Mail\RichiestaAssistenzaCreazione' not found. The class is in App/Mail/RichiestaAssistenzaCreazione.php

I don't understand why.

Comment: Try running `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have run composer dump-autoload and upload vendor folder on server. Now the error is: include(/home/badando/vendor/composer/../../app/Mail/RichiestaAssistenzaCreazione.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory